# VS2008 in vdproj, project output doesn't override an previous old version

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-installer, vdproj

I have create a solution in visual studio 2008 with two project, one is for main application code and the other is a visual deployment project (.vdproj) to create the installer.

In deployment project, I add the project output of the application code project ( .exe file) to target Application Folder. But Issues found everytime I make a new version of the installer, the .exe file cannot be override if I run the new installer on a machine with previous version of installation.

I have regenerated the product code and keep the upgrade code unchanged, also set the "RemovePreviousVersions" property of the vdproj to true, and other ordinary files are overrided correctly with the new installer.

Also I changed the version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 or so everytime I make new installers.

Anyone has met such issue, any suggestions for me, thank you very much!

ps- Finally, I get the solution here:
[Deployment project not updating .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806501/deployment-project-not-updating-exe)

Answer (score 0):

You must change the Version ( default 1.0.0 ) from build to build.   One of the first three fields must change. Allowable numbers are 0-255.0-255.0-65535.

Also the installer being updated and the installer doing the update must be installed in the same scope.   If one is Per-User and one is Per-Machine it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, but I have changed the version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1, but it still doesn't works :(

Comment: Log the installation and see what FindRelatedProducts reports.  It's hard to trouble shoot without looking at your MSI's.

Comment: I finally found the solution, please see the link I put at the end of my original post, thank you all :)